# call f:view locale from ViewScope

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tomcat7

Using Tomcat7 with CDI WELD 2.4.1. JSF 2.2.

I have a viewscope DasshBoardBean `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`and in dashboard.xhtml i use the bean like this `<f:view locale="#{dashBoardBean.locale}">` to set or get the locale that was set before from the loginbean.

e.g. a use call the login-page and want and change the through url paramater like this `login.xhmt?locale=fr` the logiBean is also a `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`.

The loginBean change the default language from german (de) to french (fr). the login page appears with the new language but when i redirect to the dashboard, the default language german comes back.

In login.xhtml
`<f:viewParam name="locale" value="#{loginBean.sessionBean.locale}" 
            converter="#{loginBean.sessionBean.localeConverter}"/>`

The local is proprely set in SessionBean, but in dashboard the jsf-tag `<f:view locale="#{dashBoardBean.locale}">` do not work proprely, i have the following error

```
WARNUNG: Using de_DE for locale because expression /shop/dashboard.xhtml @54,43 locale="#{dashBoardBean.locale}" returned null
```

How do i get the user language in dashboard.xhtml?

Thanks for your help.

```
public class BaseBean {  
            @Inject  
            SessionBean sessionBean;  
            public SessionBean getSessionBean() {  
                return this.sessionBean;  
            }  
            public Locale getLocale() {  
                return getSessionBean().getLocale();  
            }  
        }  

        @Named  
        @ViewScoped  
        public class DashboardBean extends BaseBean implements Serializable {  
        }  

    // SessionBean
    import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
    import javax.inject.Named;

    @Named
    @SessionScoped
    public class SessionBean implements Serializable {
    private Locale locale;

    public Locale getLocale() {
            if (this.locale == null) {
                this.locale = Locale.getDefault();
            }

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(this.locale);
            return this.locale;
        }
    }

// set locale when user set the url param e.g. locale=en
    public Locale getLocale(String locale) {
            String locale2 = null;
            if (locale.indexOf("_") > 0) {
                locale2 = locale.split("_")[0];
            } else {
                locale2 = locale + "_" + locale.toUpperCase();
            }

            for (Locale l : Arrays.asList(Locale.getAvailableLocales())) {
                if (l.toString().toLowerCase().equals(locale) || l.toString().toLowerCase().equals(locale2)) {
                    this.locale = l;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (this.locale == null) {
                this.locale = Locale.getDefault();
            }

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(this.locale);
            return this.locale;
        }

        public void setLocale(Locale locale) {
            this.locale = locale;
        }

        public Converter getLocalConverter() {
            return new Converter() {

                @Override
                public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return (value == null) ? null : ((Locale) value).getLanguage();
                }

                @Override
                public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return (value == null) ? null : getLocale(value);
                }
            };
        }
```

the DasboardBean call the getLocale from BaseBean. BaseBean has no @Named or @ViewScoped Annotation

Comment: Which scope has DashboardBean?

Comment: DasbBoardBean has also the `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`

Comment: works /shop/dashboard.xhtml with `locale=#{loginBean.sessionBean.locale}`? The error says `dashBoardBean.locale` isn't set.

Comment: I don't know if it's work. will try it now and get back soon..  but i don't if this is a proper way to do that. access the loginBean inside the dashboardBean.

Comment: Now i get the following error `/shop/dashboard.xhtml @54,63 locale="#{loginBean.sessionBean.locale}" WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`

Comment: Should i go back to the `@ManagedBean` with the old `ViewScope`? because it doesn't work with `@Named` and `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` on tomcat7. CDI installation guide http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html of BalusC

Comment: No, don't go back. Post your DashboardBean and set local static, works?

Comment: I've got the error only when i use the  `f:view tag`.  other tags like `f:viewParam` or `f:viewAction` do not make trouble. can someone tell me why?

Comment: i posted the dashboardBean in the original post

Comment: SessionBean is with @SessionBean annotate?

Comment: Yes, SessionBean is annotated with `@SessionBean`, see code above

Comment: can someone help me?

Comment: to solved the problem, i created a method `viewLocale` inside the `BaseBean`.  this method return a void and just delegate the call to the `SessionBean class` calling the getLocale method of `SessionBean`. And i will call the method on top of my views with a f:viewAction tag because f:view tag don't work like a mentioned above. Be aware when using f:view and CDI beans with apache tomcat. maybe it's work with other application server like glassfish, jboss, wildfly. dont know.